# How to write a query with WHERE with two conditions

Tags: sql, string, where-clause, viewpoint

Right now I have:

```
WHERE flag_1 NOT IN ("D") AND flag_2 NOT IN ("D")
```

I have two sets of people working on the same data, and once one group is completed they will "flag" it `D`, but the report will still need to pull the info until BOTH are flagged `D`.

Right now the report is excluding the data if either are flagged `D`, but I only want it excluded once both aspects are completed and flagged `D`.

Any guidance?

Comment: Please provide sample data.

Comment: How about `'D' in (flag_1, flag_2)`? You should probably look up De Morgan's laws.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I only want it excluded once both aspects are completed and flagged "D".

This would translate as:

```
WHERE NOT (flag_1 = 'D' AND flag_2 = 'D')
```

NB: I don't see the point for the `IN` operator with a single value in the list, so I changed to a simple `=`.

Answer (score 2):

```
WHERE flag_1 <> 'D' OR flag_2 <> 'D'
```

If you want the report to continue to pull the records until both flags are at `'D'`, checking the flags that don't equal `'D'` will pull them into the set.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could translate it to `WHERE flag_1 <> 'D' AND flag_2 <> 'D'`.  You can use the SQL `IN` condition (sometimes called the `IN` operator) if you want to easily test if an expression matches any value in a list of values.  In your case you have only one single value to evaluate.

`NOT` is a negation, `<> (not equal to)` is a comparison operator, they are both ISO standard. And have no performance difference.